# Is there a reason to have both Eclipse IDE for Java and also Eclipse IDE for Java EE?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I've recently downloaded the Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers (for web apps development). Does it make sense to delete my "regular" Eclipse IDE for Java developers? I mean, is there a feature in the regular IDE which isn't included in the EE IDE?

(I also use eclipse for Python programming with the Pydev plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eclipse for Java EE](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1) is a superset of [Eclipse for Java](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr1).

Answer (score 4):

The different "editions" of the eclipse IDE are basically just a different set of plugins on top of the basic eclipse platform. So if anything is missing you can alyways install those plugins when you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a super-set. 
Also, have you tried [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/web/java-ee.html)? It has better GUI, better javadoc support and it is way cooler to use! (and free)

Answer (score 1):

Not everyone needs the EE tools (mainly WTP - web tools platform); they may only be doing client apps or writing eclipse plugins.